# Prove that K is a normal subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let H be a normal subgroup of G and K={k in G: kh=hk for all h in H}. Prove that K is a normal subgroup of G.
I don't really know how to relate these all in a proof. I know that because H is a normal subgroup of G, for every element g in G, Hg=gH. But the K elements are throwing me off. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g\in G, h\in H, k\in K$, $gkg^{-1}h(gkg^{-1})^{-1}$

$=gk(g^{-1}hg)k^{-1}g^{-1}$. We know that $h'=g^{-1}hg\in H$ since $H$ is normal, we deduce that $kh'k^{-1}=h'$ and

$gk(g^{-1}hg)k^{-1}g^{-1}=g(g^{-1}hg)g^{-1}=h$. This implies that $gkg^{-1}\in K$ and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.